# Regex match all characters up to number if there is one

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out how to write a regex that will match every charter up to, but not including the first number in the character sequence if there is one.

Ex:

**Input**: abc123

**Output**: abc

**Input**: #$%@#<>@<123

**Output**: #$%@#<>@<

**Input**: abc

**Output**: abc

**Input**: abc @#@#@-122

**Output**: abc @#@#@-

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: `^\D+`................

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/kH1rC6/1

Answer (score 0):

**[Update]** Try this regex:

```
([^0-9\n]+)[0-9]?.*
```

Regex explains:

```
(           capturing group starts
[^0-9\n]    match a single character other than numbers and new line
+           match one or more times
)           capturing group ends
[0-9]       match a single digit number (0-9)
?           match zero or more times
.*          if any, match all other than new line
```

Thanks @Robbie Averill for clarifying OP's requirement. [Here is the demo.](https://regex101.com/r/jR4mT0/3)

Comment: add `a123b456` returns `a` and `b` - the OP wants to only match before the first digit

Comment: @RobbieAverill: Just updated. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
/^([^\d\n]+)\d*.*$/gm
```

This will also handle scenarios where you have multiple sets of numbers in a string. [Example here.](https://regex101.com/r/kH1rC6/2)

Explanation:

```
^          # define the start of the stirng
(          # open capture group
  [^\d\n]+ # match anything that isn't a digit or a newline that occurs once or more
)          # close capture group
\d*        # zero or more digits
.*         # anything zero or more times
$          # define the end of the string

g # global
m # multi line
```

The greedy matching will mean that by default you will match the capture group and stop capturing as soon as either a digit or anything that isn't matched in the capture group or the end of the string it encountered.

Answer (score 0):

I did not select a correct answer because the correct answer was left in the comments. "^\D+"

I am working in java, so putting it all together I got:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\D+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Testing123Testing");
String extracted = m.group(1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the character class feature: [...]

Identify numbers:  [0-9]

Negate the class:   [^0-9]

Allow as many as you like:   [^0-9]*

Comment: The question may be need improvement; the objective appears to be the use of Regex to extract all characters before any digits, and all characters if there are no digits.